# How to Not Transfer Blank Column to Master Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, transfer

This code works perfectly until the 'if' is added. The 'if' should prevent the row that has no data in column 2 from being transferred to the master sheet. How to I make data that has not data prevent from transferring.

```
    function combineSheets() {
  var sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1= sApp.getSheetByName("January");
  var s2= sApp.getSheetByName("February");
  var s3= sApp.getSheetByName("March");
  var s4= sApp.getSheetByName("April");
    var s5= sApp.getSheetByName("May");
  var s6= sApp.getSheetByName("June");
  var s7= sApp.getSheetByName("July");
  var s8= sApp.getSheetByName("August");
    var s9= sApp.getSheetByName("September");
  var s10= sApp.getSheetByName("October");
  var s11= sApp.getSheetByName("November");
  var s12= sApp.getSheetByName("December");
  var s13= sApp.getSheetByName("Master");
 

  var s1values = s1.getRange(1,2,s1.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var s2values = s2.getRange(1,2,s2.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var s3values = s3.getRange(1,2,s3.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
    var s4values = s4.getRange(1,2,s4.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var s5values = s5.getRange(1,2,s5.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var s6values = s6.getRange(1,2,s6.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
    var s7values = s7.getRange(1,2,s7.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var s8values = s8.getRange(1,2,s8.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var s9values = s9.getRange(1,2,s9.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
    var s10values = s10.getRange(1,2,s10.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var s11values = s11.getRange(1,2,s11.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var s12values = s12.getRange(1,2,s12.getLastRow(),27).getValues();
  var sourceData  =  s1values.concat(s2values,s3values,s4values,s5values,s6values,s7values,s8values,s9values,s10values,s11values,s12values);

 
    for (var i in sourceData) {
  if (sourceData[i][1] !== null && sourceData[i][1] !== '') {
    targetData.push(sourceData[i]);
  }

  var s13values = [];
  s13values =  s1values.concat(s2values,s3values,s4values,s5values,s6values,s7values,s8values,s9values,s10values,s11values,s12values);
  s13.getRange(1,1,s13values.length,27).setValues(s13values);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

I believe your goal is to transfer the data from each month sheet to the `Master` sheet except for the rows for which column `B` is empty.

- Iterate over the sheets and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) sheet get the data from the second column until column `27` and until the last row with content of the corresponding sheet.
- [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the rows for which column `B` is empty. Remember your range starts from column `B` therefore in terms of JavaScript, the `zero` element of the values array corresponds to the values of column `B`:

  ```
  sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),27).getValues().filter(r=>r[0]!='');
  ```
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is used to make sure you concatenating the values properly.
- I also improved your code both in terms of performance but also make it easier to modify it, for example change some range parameters etc.

### Solution:

```
function combineSheets() {
  const sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
                 'August','September','October','November','December'];  
  const master = sApp.getSheetByName('Master');           
  const sourceData = [];
  months.forEach(m=>{
     let sh = sApp.getSheetByName(m);
     let vals = sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),27).getValues().filter(r=>r[0]!='');
       sourceData.push(...vals);
  });
  master.getRange(1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked but now I have 2 new questions. 1.How do I sort by 2 items? I need to sort by Person and their Status (ie Completed). In the status cell is also a date, I just want it to find the completed part. 2. How to skip if the status is completed? Both of these are for the page that has already been combined. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Got it. I will post a follow-up and hopefully you can help with that as well. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65927571/sorting-by-2-variables

Comment: @retter4242 thanks for the link. Consider adding a screenshot or a sample sheet in your question so it will be easier to be answered.

Comment: Will do. I’ll have something tomorrow

Comment: I have added a sample sheet.