# Sorting by 2 variables

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a follow up to my previous question that was answered: [How to Not Transfer Blank Column to Master Sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876025/how-to-not-transfer-blank-column-to-master-sheet/65877529?noredirect=1#comment116562832_65877529)

2 new questions.

1. How do I sort by 2 items? I need to sort by Person and their Status (ie Completed). In the status cell is also a date, I just want it to find the completed part.
2. How to skip if the status is completed? Both of these are for the page that has already been combined. Hope this makes sense.

Sample Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y48N8W8CdaNlrxXopj5lnHTiNep33g_qA2-kTrPdt3A/edit#gid=130911536

```
function combineSheets() {
      const sApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
                     'August','September','October','November','December'];  
      const master = sApp.getSheetByName('Master');           
      const sourceData = [];
      months.forEach(m=>{
         let sh = sApp.getSheetByName(m);
         let vals = sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),27).getValues().filter(r=>r[0]!='');
           sourceData.push(...vals);
      });
      master.getRange(1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
}
```

Comment: To help us visualize. Kindly attach a sample sheet.

Comment: This code is working, but I want to add to it with the questions I asked.

Comment: Sorry, I will reword questions. Does the link work now?

Comment: So yes to question 1. I want to discard then sort. Question 2 is for a separate import for a different workbook. I included it here to hopefully make everything easier

Comment: The column "Person" is missing in your sample sheet and the word "Completed" can only be found in the 5th column.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *In my example, I removed the `Other Data` columns from your example to make the sheet cleaner. I also added `Person` column.*

Try this:

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
function filternsort() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  //get sheet1 data
  var val = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var completed = [];
  var notcompleted = [];
  //start to 1 to exclude header
  for (var i = 1; i < val.length; i++) {
    if(val[i][5].toString().match(/Completed.+/)){
      //add to array completed if it matches the word Completed in the Date Due column
      completed.push(val[i]);
    }else{
      //add to array notcompleted if not match.
      notcompleted.push(val[i]);
    }
  }
  //insert header to the beginning of the array
  completed.unshift(val[0]);
  //set filtered values
  sheet2.getRange(1, 1, completed.length, completed[0].length).setValues(completed);
  //sort by Person
  sheet2.getRange(2, 1, completed.length, completed[0].length).sort(1);

  //insert header to the beginning of the array
  notcompleted.unshift(val[0]);
  //set filtered values
  sheet3.getRange(1, 1, notcompleted.length, notcompleted[0].length).setValues(notcompleted);
  //sort by Person
  sheet3.getRange(2, 1, notcompleted.length, notcompleted[0].length).sort(1);  
}
```

**Sheet2:**

[image]

**Sheet3:**

[image]

References:

- [Array.prototype.unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)
- [Range.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)
- [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: How do I make only one person show up? I want all of johns stuff to show up if E does not contain Completed.

Comment: Since Sheet3 contains all Person that does not have Completed in Column F, you can just create a Filter by going to Data-> Create filter -> Click the filter icon besides the Person column header -> uncheck all except for John.